# XSLT 2.0 Time Display

Tags: xml, date, xslt, time

I'm having trouble in getting my desired output. I already search alot from internet but still no luck that's why I'm posting this simple problem(maybe to most of expert)

This code will generate the current time date with utc format

```
    <xsl:variable name="utc"
  select="
           adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(
              current-dateTime(),
              xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H'))
              "/>
```

Output eg.
`2015-11-08T12:13:18.634Z`

I just want to display the year and time without the after seconds datas ".634Z"
Desired output:

```
2015-11-08T12:13:18
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `format-dateTime` with a proper picture string, the documentation at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g. `format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')`, see the documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples.